# When to use @xw.arg and @xw.ret for writing UDFs in xlwings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlwings

Some xlwings UDFs use @xw.arg and @xw.ret. Some don't. Under what situation should a developer use @xw.arg and @xw.ret when writing UDFs in xlwings? Is this a matter of best practice that a developer should follow all the time? Something like python typing?

I am using xlwings 0.19.4, python 3.7, Excel 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#xw-arg-and-xw-ret-decorators):

These decorators are to UDFs what the options method is to Range objects: they allow you to apply converters and their options to function arguments (@xw.arg) and to the return value (@xw.ret). For example, to convert the argument x into a pandas DataFrame and suppress the index when returning it, you would do the following:

```
@xw.func
@xw.arg('x', pd.DataFrame)
@xw.ret(index=False)
def myfunction(x):
   # x is a DataFrame, do something with it
   return x
```